# Request custom fields in webdav client

Tags: node.js, curl, webdav, nextcloud

I have tried many different ways of reading the directory of nextCloud api with custom details such as this:

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <d:propfind xmlns:d="DAV:">
   <d:prop xmlns:oc="http://owncloud.org/ns">
     <d:getlastmodified/>
     <d:getcontentlength/>
     <d:getcontenttype/>
     <oc:permissions/>
     <d:resourcetype/>
     <oc:share-types />
     <oc:fileid />
     <d:getetag/>
   </d:prop>
 </d:propfind>'
```

First, I tried with running curl command using child_process such as this:

```
var command = `curl -u username:password 'https://cloud.example.com/remote.php/dav/files/username/folder' -X PROPFIND --data '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <d:propfind xmlns:d="DAV:">
   <d:prop xmlns:oc="http://owncloud.org/ns">
     <d:getlastmodified/>
     <d:getcontentlength/>
     <d:getcontenttype/>
     <oc:permissions/>
     <d:resourcetype/>
     <d:getetag/>
   </d:prop>
 </d:propfind>'`

import { exec } from "child_process"

const child = exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
            return;
        }
        if (stderr) {
            console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
            return;
        }
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);

        return stdout;
      });
```

When I run this, I am getting this error message which does not say what is wrong with it

```
error: Command failed: curl -u username:password 'https://cloud.example.com/remote.php/dav/files/username/folder' -X PROPFIND --data '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <d:propfind xmlns:d="DAV:">
   <d:prop xmlns:oc="http://owncloud.org/ns">
     <d:getlastmodified/>
     <d:getcontentlength/>
     <d:getcontenttype/>
     <oc:permissions/>
     <d:resourcetype/>
     <d:getetag/>
   </d:prop>
 </d:propfind>'
```

But when I copy the same curl command that the error message returned back on another instance of terminal, I am getting the right xml file printed on the console. I am really confused why this is happening? Also, I would like to save the stdout to a xml variable to use it later? How can I accomplish that as well? I am stuck over this issue for many hours and I can not seem to figure out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Instead of calling a curl executable and dealing with complex escaping, have you considered just using a HTTP client for Node.js?

Comment: Yes, I tried the http request but I was not successful in that either: 

      var headers = {
        "Content-Type": "text/xml"
      };
      require('http').request({
        url: `${env.IVC_URL}`,
        data: data,
        headers: headers,
        method: "PROPFIND",
        json: false,
        encoding: "utf8",
        auth: {
          user: `${env.USER}`,
          password: `${env.PASSWORD}`
        }
      }, function(res:any) {
        res.resume();
      }).end();

Comment: And I am getting this error with http request: typeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. data is my xml string.

Comment: you should share the code you wrote for this, and the error messages in your question. You can press edit to make changes. Too hard to understand from the comments!